# Querying DB based on id field but passing title in URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Here's what I am trying to do.

I have a defined route

```
Route::get('/{id}', [
'uses' => 'questionsController@show'
]);
```

Basically I am searching for a record in my questions model using Id.

In the questions controller the code for show method is

```
public function show($id)
{
    $question = questions::find($id);
    return view ('show', compact('question'));
}
```

On another view I have the following code

```
<a href = "/questions/"{{ $questions--> id }}> {{ $question->title }}</a>
```

Basically I am anchor tagging the Title with the id of the page to make sure when someone clicks on the link they are redirected /questions/id
This is where the id is queried.

How can I replace the anchor tag to the title of the question so that the URL becomes 
/questions/How do I swim

and yet the model is queried based on id (since id is the primary key)?

Comment: is in your model questions.php ? or Questions.php?

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Comment: thanks dlporter. I think the slug makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a url slug, [the part of a URL which identifies a page using human-readable keywords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug).

There is a Laravel plug-in called 'Eloquent-Sluggable' that was built specifically to solve this problem. You may find it at https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

The documentation is quite good; you should find it easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with

```
<a href="/questions/{{ $question->id }}">{{ $question->title }}</a>
```

Doing this your url becomes /questions/ID_OF_QUESTION if you want it's to use /questions/title-of-the-question the difference it's that you need to change the way that you are querying the question. Use slugs to identify the questions because "How do I swing" it's not properly URL parsed and maybe two users make the same question.

Or

using the route /questions/id/title-of-the-question, but note that the text that comes after the id will be indiferent